# Use csc.exe to compile assembly referencing COM DLL

Tags: c#

How could I compile a .cs program that references a COM DLL from the command line?

Assume I have COM DLL with the following path: C:\Projects\com1.dll
Assume C# code is in file: C:\Projects\program.cs

I've tried this
csc.exe /lib:"C:\Projects" /reference:com1.dll "C:\Projects\program.cs"

hoping to get program.exe  This fails so the references for COM dlls by this method is wrong route.

-- Adding specifics in reference to first answer --
Okay assuming in this case I'm using ADO

```
tlbimp "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Syste \ado\msador15.dll"
```

Get this response

```
Type library imported to ADOR.dll
```

Now placing that new DLL created by tlbimp into the same directory as a program that has using ADODB in it:

```
csc /lib:. /reference:ADOR.dll Program.cs
```

Returns

```
Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246: 
The type or namespace name 'ADODB' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

-- Overloads Issue --

```
using System;
using ADODB;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        connection.Open(args[0]);
        //connection.Open(args[0], "", "", -1);
        Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an interop assembly with tlbimp (or by hand) and reference that, not the COM dll directly. You'll run tlbimp on com1.dll and then reference Interop.com1.dll (or whatever you call the interop) that tlbimp generates. Note that to use tlbimp the COM component must have a type library.

tlbimp's default namespace is going to be `Interop.Foo`, not `Foo`, if you want to specify `Foo` you need to use `/namespace:Foo`.

Comment: Okay - tried that.  Using ADO COM DLL as specific example.  No luck.  Am I missing something else?  Maybe ADO lacks the type library.  No error messages from tlbimp.exe.

Comment: Are you sure ADODB is the correct namespace to use? You can use ildasm or reflector to poke around in the generated assembly.

Comment: No, ADODB was not the correct namespace.  Just assumed it because this was the namespace Visual Studio gave me when I added it in there with via Add Reference - COM.  I checked it in Reflector and its ADOR so I forced ADODB namespace.  Problem is that is doesn't seem like it wants to bring in all the classes.  The Connection, which shows when you hook in from Visual Studio is missing.  It won't compile it from the command line either if I want to instantiate a Connection object. Its like it only sets up part of what is available.

Comment: Maybe I need to post another question, but I know Visual Studio can compile it when I add a COM Reference via Solutions Explorer where is uses namespace ADODB.  Is there anyway to find out all the command line's that Visual Studio is executing when it builds a project?

Comment: For me, Connection is in msado15.dll, not msador15.dll.

Comment: msado15.dll - this solves the Connection object problem.  Unfortunately a new one is created.  It doesn't bring in all the method overloads for some reason.  For example, connectionInstance.Execute() acts like the only method signature of Execute is one in which there are 3 arguments.  Its ignoring multiple overloads for this method (and others) like only the method call with the most arguments exists.  And it works in Visual Studio just fine.  You can Add the COM reference to the DLL and call connectionInstance.Execute() with 1 argument and it doesn't complain.

Comment: I'm fairly certain COM interfaces don't support multiple overloads of the same method. You can have optional arguments, but not overloading.

Comment: One of the things confusing me the most was I was able to get everything working in Visual Studio.  Multiple overloads work there. Digging deeper and enabling more verbose output on the build I discovered that when I installed 2010 it didn't update my Path.  So calling csc from the command line used 3.5 instead of 4.  So that was part of the problem.  The 4 csc also seems to have a new flag. It wasn't using reference: but  "/link:obj\x86\Release\Interop.ADODB.dll".  So that's a piece of the puzzle.  I may need to go back to an image with VS2008 so I can get the verbose output on a 3.5 compile.

Comment: link just embeds the interop types into your assembly. It is a space saving measure for COM interops and you don't need to ship/deploy the interop assembly. As far as Execute having multiple overloads, I'm not seeing any evidence of this in the docs for ADO, and like I said, COM doesn't have any mechanism for exposing overloads.

Comment: I don't know enough about how COM and .NET work together to say anything about how overloads work. I added some code above to my question.  That sample code will compile and run in VS2010.  It will not compile via CSC.  You get this error message "Program.cs(9,9): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Open' takes '1' arguments Interop.ADODB1.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)".  Yet it takes 1 argument from VS2010.  It will compile if I replace it with the line commented out where 3 arguments are used.

Comment: You will get a similar overload error for Execute() if you add that to the example. Just keeping the example simple to illustrate that VS2010 is able to compile in more cases than CSC around "overloads".  Maybe I'm just missing something else from the command line. I will explore the build verbose output for csc in more detail eventually and see if adding and removing options makes a difference.  I'm using the very simple "csc /r:Interop.ADODB1.dll Program.cs" to compile above. It works with the 3 arg option, but not the 1. VS2010 works for both.

Comment: @iiff the ability to make use of the default argument information in the assembly seems to be a new feature of the 4.0 version of csc. If you use the 4.0 version of csc (SDK version 7.1), which is also the version of the compiler VS 2010 is going to use, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for sticking with it for so long even after I marked it as the answer.